# List of changes from last year in one file

Tags: tfs

I've been asked to present a list of all changes made to a file in the last year with TFS2013. I have no clue how to go about this, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to achieve this:

1#

Right click the file and select Find-->Find Changesets, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Then choose Created date, and specify the date, Click Find, you'll see the list of all changes made to a file in the last year:

[image]

2#

Use [History command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh(v=vs.120).aspx):

```
c:\code\SiteApp\Main\SolutionA\Project1>tf history program2.cs /v:D1/1/2015~D12/31/2015
```

3#

Install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), and open History Sidekick, you'll see all changesets for a file and export it to a .csv file.